SDE's and Frechet derivatives
I'm learning the basics of SDE's, and it's usually stated that an SDE like
$$dX_t = \mu(X_t, t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t)dW_t \tag{1}$$
is an abbreviation for the stochastic integral equation
$$X_{t+h} - X_t = \int_t^{t+h} \mu(X_s, s) ds + \int_t^{t+h} \sigma(X_s,s)dW_s \tag{2}$$
for each $t,t+h$ in the domain. However, I was wondering if it's possible to instead interpret $(1)$ as a more "true" differential equation
$$\frac{dX_t}{dt} = \mu(X_t, t) + \sigma(X_t,t)\frac{dW_t}{dt} \tag{3}$$
where the derivatives are understood as Frechet derivatives on $L^2$. (Here, I assume $\frac{dW_t}{dt}$ turns out to be a white noise process.) To what extent do solutions to $(2)$ and $(3)$ coincide? Are there any obvious conditions under which the equations are equivalent? And does this have something to do with Malliavin calculus, which I don't know anything about?

The pathwise formulation is necessarily more complicated than your (3). There is a way to do it using something called rough path theory.

You are learning the basics of SDE's. At this stage it is not a good idea to ask MSE to give a full overview of the other subjects SDEs are related to: white noise, Malliavin calculus (of which you know nothing) and what not. We cannot repeat stuff here that is handled in standard textbooks that need to be studied.

I wasn't asking for a full overview.

A honest person trying to answer that question will only end up giving a full overview or at least a list of textbooks (which you can google yourself). Dropping just terms is in my opinion a waste of time.

Look, I wasn't even chiefly asking about connections to Malliavin calculus, that was more of a side question. I just wanted to know if there was a well-understood sense in which the SDE could be understood via Frechet derivatives rather than Ito integrals.

So let's drop Malliavin calculus. The white noise theory ends up defining $dW_t/dt$ as a distribution valued stochastic process. In my opinion that whole strand of literature is completely redundant but we can't stop peoples (mostly from physics) having their hobbies. I admit that I know little about Frechet derivatives. Hint: does a Frechet derivative give us a distribution (generalized function) or an ordinary function? This might answer one of your questions.
